# App not working, binary working

Tags: macos, applications, plist, binary

I have a Wine app that allows me to run a windows game on a mac. However for some reason, if I open the app directly, the binary file within opens, but it does not seem to run as intended and doesn't do its "magic" of running the exe file.

However if I go inside the package contents of the app, through `/Contents/MacOS/WineskinLauncher` (where the WineskinLauncher is the set Executable File to be opened as shown in the Info.plist) and double-click that binary, it actually does it's job of running the windows exe program (along with opening a Terminal window first). Confused as to why this happens, I went to Activity Monitor to see what files and ports were being opened and I found some similarities and oddities.

> Through broken .app:
>
> ```
> cwd
> /
> txt
> /private/var/folders/7p/kk88nfm571bcg3y04xk4x_gh0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/E780487B-7603-4301-93C5-F79C5C77DC8D/d/SomeGame.app/Contents/MacOS/WineskinLauncher
> txt
> /usr/share/icu/icudt57l.dat
> txt
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
> txt
> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantLightAppearance.car
> txt
> /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
> txt
> /System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText.ttf
> txt
> /System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
> txt
> /usr/lib/dyld
> txt
> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
> txt
> /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
> 0
> /dev/null
> 1
> /dev/null
> 2
> /dev/null
> 3
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
> ```
>
> Through working binary:
>
> ```
> cwd
> /Users/Admin
> txt
> /Users/Admin/Documents/Games/SomeGame.app/Contents/MacOS/WineskinLauncher
> txt
> /usr/share/icu/icudt57l.dat
> txt
> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/SystemAppearance.car
> txt
> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/VibrantLightAppearance.car
> txt
> /System/Library/Caches/com.apple.IntlDataCache.le.kbdx
> txt
> /System/Library/Fonts/SFNSText.ttf
> txt
> /System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/AppleKeyboardLayouts-L.dat
> txt
> /usr/lib/dyld
> txt
> /private/var/folders/7p/kk88nfm571bcg3y04xk4x_gh0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-175-v2.csstore
> txt
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
> txt
> /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h
> 0
> /dev/ttys001
> 1
> /dev/ttys001
> 2
> /dev/ttys001
> 3
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Extras2.rsrc
> ```

I'm suspecting that there must be something wrong with the settings of the plist file.

Here is the info.plist
[image]

**How do I make it so I can properly run the app just by double clicking the app rather than having to go inside it and run the binary directly?**